# How to load multiple images from multiple folders from "train" folder in Google Colab?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, read-write

[image: I want to find those images and assign it to train variable as shown. Problem is mine one is not a gzip file. Mine one is 6 folders, each with 40 images(.jpg) in it. So which command to use?]I am using Google Colab for ML model on Food classification. My train folder contains 6 subfolders. I want to read all images and assign it to train_images variable as shown. The problem is that I have 6 folders, each with 40 images(.jpg) in it.  So what should be the code? I am using python for this.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
>>> for folder in os.listdir('desktop/images'):
...     for image in os.listdir(f'desktop/images/{folder}'): print(image)
...
20160327_174551.jpg
20160327_174559.jpg
20160327_174636.jpg
20160327_174718.jpg
20160327_174756.jpg
20160327_174810.jpg
```

There were six folders in the images directory with one image in each folder. These two for loops will find all of the images.